# HTML5 video embedding

Tags: html, .htaccess, google-chrome, firefox, video

I am trying to embed HTML5 video in bootstrap 2.2.2 based design but it is not working on Firefox, however it is working fine with chrome but on firefox it says `No video with supported format and MIME type found.`
I have tried adding these to .htaccess file and uploaded this to my root directory but this didn't helped either.

- AddType video/mp4  mp4 m4v
- AddType audio/mp4  m4a
- AddType video/ogg ogv
- AddType audio/ogg  ogg oga
- AddType video/webm webm

I have also converted videos into different html supported format and tried to add but no luck.
[This is the page where I am adding videos and you can see the source](http://ritzcarltonmiamibeach.com/index-10.html)

**Note: I went to through previous questions on stackoverflow but no luck there and I do not have apache config files to allow video style as I am on shared hosting.**

Comment: Hi!
I got the feeling that you described behaviour is related to this problem (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57189/htaccess-protected-html5-videos-not-playing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, both your webm and ogg files are throwing a 404 error - file not found.
secondly, in your question you have the right mime type, but in the code you are using

```
video/ogv
```

which is incorrect. it should be

```
video/ogg
```

EDIT

Furthermore, you should not be using the same id on the elements `id="video"` rather e.g. `id="video1"`.

However these are not the real problem you are facing. If you have indeed uploaded the files,  if it won't play, firefox will still try to download it. My intuition tells me it is something to do with your htaccess...

The reason why I say this is because I discovered that the server is doing some wacky redirection, and this is a valid address that enables the browser to download the mp4:

```
http://ritzcarltonmiamibeach.com/ritzcarltonmiamibeach.com/videos/aerial.mp4
```

Why don't you post your entire htaccess?

Comment: Strange, Video is available in that folder and now I have even tried putting the video in root directory of the hosting but still returns 404 error. I have even tried using those videos on localhost and they work just fine on Firefox.I am startled, is there something I am missing?

Comment: I guess your htaccess is somehow messed up. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the config files on server (hosting provider confirmed this). Now I have got permission to use embedded videos, so everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://mediaelementjs.com/

Seems to have good reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with denjello that your server might be doing some strange redirection. However, this does not seem to be a problem for the mp4 files, which I was able to access directly from the browser, even with the strange redirection.

So it's likely that webm videos are disabled from another place. It will be difficult to find out exactly what is going on since, as you say, you have no access to the apache config files. Have you asked your hosting company about this?

I know this is not the optimal solution, but you can consider loading the videos from another server. I would recommend that you try this at least for testing purposes to rule out other sources of errors.